# See if a value exists in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In Python to check if a value is in a list you can simply do the following:

```
>>>9 in [1,2,3,6,9]
True
```

I would like to do the same for a Pandas DataFrame but unfortunately Pandas does not recognise that notation:

```
>>>import pandas as pd
>>>df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]],columns=["a","b","c","d"])
   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  3  4
1  5  6  7  8
>>>7 in df
False
```

How would I achieve this using Pandas DataFrame without iterating through each column/row or anything complicated?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically you have to check the matrix without the schema, so:

```
 7 in df.values
```

`x in df` checks if `x` is in the columns:

```
for x in df:
    print x,

out: a b c d
```