# speed up pandas search for a certain value not in the whole df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a large pandas DataFrame consisting of some 100k rows and ~100 columns with different dtypes and arbitrary content.

I need to assert that it does not contain a certain value, let's say `-1`.
Using `assert( not (any(test1.isin([-1]).sum()>0)))` results in processing time of some seconds.

Any idea how to speed it up?

Comment: How about negating the results of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573999/see-if-a-value-exists-in-a-dataframe?

Comment: @Sparky05 : Thanks, `assert (not( -1 in test1.values )) ` leads to approx. 50% speed up. A bit less than I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make a full answer out of my comment:

With `-1 not in test1.values` you can check if `-1` is in your DataFrame.

Regarding the performance, this still needs to check every single value, which is in your case

`10^5*10^2 = 10^7`.

You only save with this the performance cost for summation and an additional comparison of these results.